# Adivinar el sexo de las personas a partir de sus nombres árabes

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo una `dataframe` con nombres y apellidos árabes y me gustaría adivinar el sexo.

```
    firstname   lastname    birthdate               new_professionactuelle  new_regiononame     new_communeoname
0   Ferhat      Abbas       1899-08-24 00:00:00     Ecrivain                Jijel               Bouafourna  
1   Ahmed       Ben Bella   1916-12-25 00:00:00     combattant              Oranie              Maghnia
```

Por el momento utilizo:

```
import gender_guesser.detector as gender

d = gender.Detector()

df['firstname']=df['firstname'].str.capitalize()
df['sex'] = df['firstname'].apply(d.get_gender)
```

Pero esto no es eficiente. El detector no adivinó el 47,35% de estos nombres como:

```
6               Lahoucine
8                Zakaria 
9                  Otmane
17                Nossair
18                 Lahcen
19              Abdelaziz
...
```

Comment: A que te refieres exactamente con "adivinar"? No es muy concreto...

Comment: No entiendo muy bien tu pregunta. `d.get_gender` te debería retornar `male` o `female` en función del `firstname`, es decir, la predicción ya estaría resuelta. Estas usando esta librería: https://github.com/lead-ratings/gender-guesser?

Comment: @PatricioMoracho Sí, pero poco más de la mitad de los nombres tienen su sexo `male` o `female` adivinado. Estoy tratando de averiguar si hay métodos más eficientes

Comment: @l3xium Es decir, si te llamas Mike, supongo que eres un hombre...

Comment: Adivinar el genero de un nombre al 100% es mas complejo, trata utilizando machine learning

Comment: ¿Estás llevando algún curso de Machine Learning, Inteligencia artificial o algo relacionado? O ¿estás a pura documentación mediante prueba y error? O ¿cómo estás aprendiendo estos temas?

Comment: @fredyfx 
estoy a pura documentación mediante prueba y error. Soy un desarrollador valiente, pero me gustaría ser bueno en NLP.

Comment: @IggyPass Con esa actitud hermano, sí o sí me encantaría trabajar algún proyecto contigo en alguna oportunidad que se presente. Por otro lado, regístrate aquí https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/dev-essentials/ y te darán un código de acceso para el sitio de Pluralsight donde hay cursos del tema y también te dan acceso a https://www.datacamp.com/ donde hacen uso intensivo de python. Los mejores éxitos, llegarás muy lejos :D

Answer (score 0):

Desconozco si hay muchos nombres árabes válidos para ambos géneros, pero podrías tener dos listas, una de nombres masculinos comunes y otra de nombres femeninos comunes, y comprobar si el valor firstname de cada fila está en una u otra. No va a ser perfecto, pero me cuesta creer que no mejore un 52,65%.

Aquí hay [listas](https://www.familyeducation.com/baby-names/browse-origin/first-name/arabic) de nombres árabes femeninos y masculinos.